What method can I use for parsing Named Ranges from Excel into C++: Alternatives to xlnt?
I'm trying to create a C++ program that imports data from named ranges in Excel. Named ranges are defined in Excel using the Name Manager (Formulas > Name Manager), and I need to extract values from them into C++ objects like single values, vectors, and arrays.
However, I'm struggling to find a reliable method to do this. I initially found some examples using the xlnt library, but I ran into many errors (e.g., missing methods like to_int() and to_double()), and I wasn’t sure how to fix them. So, I abandoned xlnt and tried using COM to directly access Excel data, but this has been complicated. I'm having trouble understanding how to manage types like LPOLESTR, _variant_t, and DISPPARAMS, and I can’t get the data retrieval to work correctly.
I started by copying some examples that used the xlnt library, expecting it to handle the Excel file and named range parsing. However, I ran into too many errors that I didn’t know how to resolve. I switched to using COM, expecting this to give me more control, but I quickly ran into new issues with type conversions and dispatch methods. At this point, I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach or if there’s a better method I should be looking at.

COM is the right way to go; however SO is not a tutorial site and it sounds like you need to do some background reading on COM,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
